# Drawing small-multiple charts with matplotlib - how to set figure size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing small multiples with matplotlib. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4, 4)
for name in ccgs:
    x = np.array([k for k in ccgs[name]['dates']])
    y = np.array([v for v in ccgs[name]['values']])
    axarr[i / 4, i % 4].plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This works brilliantly when the output is  a 4x4 grid, but pretty dreadfully when I start adding more subplots.

It looks like this - the fact that only the first 16 charts have data is irrelevant, it's the squashedness I'm concerned about:

[image]

How can I stretch the figure produced by matplotlib so each chart is a reasonable height?

I had assumed it would be possible simply to set the total pixel height of the figure, but I'm not getting very far with Google.

I don't care if the interactive output produced by matplotlib is not very usable, as long as I can produce a final `.png` file that is sensible.

Answer (score 2):

```
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(15, 10, figsize=(15, 10))
for ax in ax_lst.ravel():
    ax.xaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(nbins=3)
    ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(nbins=2)

fig.tight_layout(pad=0, h_pad=.1, w_pad=.1)
```

[image]

or

```
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(15, 10, figsize=(15, 10), sharex='col', sharey='row')
for ax in ax_lst.ravel():
    ax.xaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(nbins=3)
    ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(nbins=2)

fig.tight_layout(pad=0, h_pad=.1, w_pad=.1)
```

[image]